# Run command specifically for Non Interactive shell except for SCP

Tags: linux, shell, scp

I'm trying to run an executable in Non interactive shell. So, I tried the below format of bash file and it works fine.

```
!/bin/bash/
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
       /bin/main
else
       return 0
fi
```

Now, I need this **"main"** executable to be excluded during an **SCP** session but couldn't find an Environment variable to exclude the **SCP** session in the bash file.

Comment: Have you considered using sftp instead of scp? (sftp uses a completely independent subsystem -- no shells involved anywhere).

Comment: Closely related, over on [unix.se]: [How to distinguish ssh from scp in `~/.ssh/rc`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657250/how-to-distinguish-ssh-from-scp-in-ssh-rc)

Answer (score 1):

When you run a bash shell script, it is always non-interactive (except if the invoker is an interactive bash which **sources** the script, or if someone **explicitly** invokes the script with `bash -i`).

If you really need to know, whether or not your bash is interactive, you can do it like this:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
  echo this bash is interactive
fi
```

The `$-` variable is explained in the section *Special Parameters* in the bash man-page.

Comment: I'm actually placing this bash script (which invokes "main" file) in profile.d which in turn runs after system login, but it is also being invoked during "SCP" which I want to exlcude.

Comment: @Umesh : I don't see how `scp` possibly would execute a script under the hood, but in any case, you can test for interactivity in the way I described it. But I wonder whether you perhaps want to query "login shell" vs. "non-login shell" instead?

Comment: No, I wanted to execute a script just after login and so placed it in profile.d, but to this script is being executed whenever I tried to open terminal. So, I used the above code to exclude terminal ( Interactive shell) execution. But this is not excluding when I do `scp`. Since, `scp` is considered as Non Interactive shell. So I don't understand how I can differentiate it.

Comment: @Umesh, ...hint: Look at your environment variables.

Comment: Did you read the part of the man-page I refered to? It explains how you can differentiate for login-shells. But in your case, I would do  a different approach: Add a parameter to your script, which basically says _yes, execute main_ or _no, do not execute main_. Make the default value of the parameter be _yes_. Inside profile.d, you invoke it explicitly with _yes_. In every other case, it takes the default,  _no_.